# compare validation rule fails in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2

I am using yii2, I have three fields num1,num2,num3.
I want to add validation, num2 input should be greater than num1 input, so I am using compare rule. Here is the code

```
        return [
            [['num1', 'num2', 'num3'], 'required'],
            [['num1', 'num2', 'num3'], 'integer', 'min' => self::MIN_SIZE, 'max' => self::MAX_SIZE],  
            ['num2', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'num1', 'operator' => '>'],
        ];
    }
```

Issue:
It works if I add 8,9,10 in the inputs but fails If I add 8,10,11 in the inputs. I have tried adding input type as number.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operands are compared as strings by default in `yii\validators\CompareValidator`. That's why `'10'` is considered less than `'8'`.

You need to set [`CompareValidator::$type`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-comparevalidator#$type-detail) property to compare operands as numbers.

Your rule should look like this:

```
[
    'num2',
    'compare',
    'compareAttribute' => 'num1',
    'operator' => '>',
    'type' => \yii\validators\CompareValidator::TYPE_NUMBER
]
```